# nth term of the series 1, 16, 24, 1024

Tags: square-numbers

What will be the formula for finding nth term of the series

for eq

for n = 1 it will be 1

for n = 2 it will be 16

for n = 3 it will be 100

for n = 4 it will be 1024

And am i doing it the correct way?

Comment: $1000$ is not a perfect square.

Comment: yes then help me correcting the series and finding the nth term

Comment: Corrected it ..

Comment: According to wikipedia 0 is technically a square number so for n=1 it is 0 not 1. So, it depends if you are working with just the positive integers, or just the non-negative integers : .https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Square_number

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The smallest is $\lceil \sqrt{10^{n-1}} \rceil^2$.  Of course if $n$ is odd, that is just $10^{n-1}$.

See [OEIS sequence A061432](https://oeis.org/A061432)

Answer (score 3):

If $n$ is odd, then it's $10^{n-1}$, as Robert Israel says. And if $n$ is even, we get

$16=4^2$
$1024=32^2$
$100489=317^2$
$10004569=3163^2$
$1000014129=31623^2$
$\ldots$

Look at the numbers on the right-hand side of these equations, and see if you can spot how they are connected to the square root of $10$, which is
$$3.16227766\ldots$$

What do you think the next number in the sequence is?